# Мульти выбор файлов для отправки на сервер

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Необходимо реализовать выбор файлов из папок DICM и Downloads (два отдельных выбора) перед отправкой на сервер.

Сейчас есть реализация этого за счет `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);`, но этот метод работает c 18 версией Android SDK.

Как можно реализовать мульти-выбор для устройств работающих с 14 версией SDK?

Пример кода прикрепляю.

Событие onClick:

```
        final View.OnClickListener mediaBtn = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //toggleStatusView(v);
            String intentType = "", intentResult = "";
            int requestCode = 0;
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.status_row_media:
                    requestCode = 1;
                    intentType = "image/*,video/*";
                    intentResult = "Select Picture";
                    String m_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();
                    File f = new File(m_path);
                    String strDirSize = "Размер фотографий: " + Long.toString(dirSize(f) / 1000000) + " мб";
                    showDirSize(strDirSize);
                    break;
                case R.id.status_row_doc:
                    requestCode = 2;
                    intentResult = "Select a File to Upload";
                    intentType = "*/*";
                    break;
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 17) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType(intentType); //For choosing both images and/or videos
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true); //This should allow multiple selection
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, intentResult), requestCode);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType(intentType); //For choosing both images and/or videos
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, intentResult),requestCode);
            }
        }

    };
```

Обработка ответа:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // List<Bitmap> photos = null;
    switch (requestCode){
        // Media files selected
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                mediaFiles.clear();
                if(data.getData() != null){
                    //If uploaded with Android Gallery (max 1 image)
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    mediaFiles.add(new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage, MEDIA_FILES)));
                } else {
                    //If uploaded with the new Android Photos gallery
                    ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
                    int count = clipData.getItemCount();
                    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                        ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                        mediaFiles.add(new File(getRealPathFromURI(item.getUri(), MEDIA_FILES)));
                        //mediaFiles.add(new File(item.getUri()));
                    }
                    counterMedia.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    counterMedia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.d("mediaFiles : ", String.valueOf(mediaFiles));
                }
            }
            break;
        // Docs files selected
        case 2:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                docsFiles.clear();
                if(data.getData() != null){
                    //If uploaded with Android Gallery (max 1 image)
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    docsFiles.add(new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage, DOCS_FILES)));
                    Log.d("docsFiles : ", String.valueOf(docsFiles));
                } else {
                    //If uploaded with the new Android Photos gallery
                    ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
                    int count = clipData.getItemCount();
                    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                        ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                        String path = FileUtils.getPath(this,item.getUri());
                        docsFiles.add(new File(path));
                        //docsFiles.add(new File(getRealPathFromURI(item.getUri(), DOCS_FILES)));
                        //docsFiles.add(new File(item.getUri()));
                    }
                    counterDocs.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    counterDocs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.d("docsFiles : ", String.valueOf(docsFiles));
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri, int typeOfFiles) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();
        String path = "";
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        } else {

            cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    contentUri,
                    null, null, new String[]{document_id}, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
        cursor.close();
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: можно не использовать системный пикер файлов, а сделать свой.

Comment: А что мешает вам получить список файлов из одной папки и из другой и вывести это на экран в виде списка и предложить пользователю сделать множественный выбор?

Comment: Если не хочется писать свой зайдите на android arsenal, там что такое было))

Comment: @Contact Спасибо, еле нашел и настроил)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Благодаря пользователю Contact нашел пикеры на [android arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/), спасибо.

Вот сами пикеры которые мне понравились:

выбор медиа - github.com/learnNcode/MediaChooser

выбор файлов - github.com/spacecowboy/NoNonsense-FilePicker

Я их неделю выбирал, надеюсь кому-то поможет.